# Assistance with Firebird SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird-psql

I have a very simple stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_BALANCE_USD
(
  PER SMALLINT
)
RETURNS
(
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER CHAR(21),
  AMOUNT NUMERIC(15, 4)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        L.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUM(-(CURRROUND(L.DEBIT,2) - CURRROUND(L.CREDIT,2)))
    FROM
        LEDGER L
    WHERE
        L.LEDGER_ACCOUNT = '31621' AND L.PERIOD = :PER
    GROUP BY
        L.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
    INTO
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT
END;
```

I am getting an error:

> TOKEN UNKNOWN LINE 22 COLUMN 1.

Line 22 column 1 refers to the last line of the code.

Somewhere I am making a really simple syntax error and for some reason I am not able to track it down. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error are you getting?? Remember: we **cannot** see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you'll have to **SHOW US** the exact and complete error message you're getting !

Comment: Hi, apologies. I thought my mistake is very straightforward that someone will be able to point it out straight away. The error message is:

TOKEN UNKNOWN LINE 22 COLUMN 1.

Line 22 column 1 refers to the last line of the code

Answer (score 2):

A token unknown error always includes the unknown token in the error message, in this case the unknown token is `END`:

```
Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 23, column 1
END
```

Inside a stored procedure, each statement must end with a semi-colon.

The corrected procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_BALANCE_USD
(
  PER SMALLINT
)
RETURNS
(
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER CHAR(21),
  AMOUNT NUMERIC(15, 4)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        L.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUM(-(CURRROUND(L.DEBIT,2) - CURRROUND(L.CREDIT,2)))
    FROM
        LEDGER L
    WHERE
        L.LEDGER_ACCOUNT = '31621' AND L.PERIOD = :PER
    GROUP BY
        L.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
    INTO
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT;
END
```

Notice the `;` after `AMOUNT` on the last line of the `SELECT` statement.